# How can you format a date with a carriage return in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet that is used to summarize monthly data. The cell contains a date.
I want to format certain dates to include text as follows:

```
February Direct Hours   |  March Direct Hours
```

to look like

```
February                |  March 
Direct Hours            |  Direct Hours
```

How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

From: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=54503

The only way to enter a line break is when you edit the text in the cell: double-click on the cell itself and you can enter a line break by typing Ctrl+Enter. It doesn't work when you're typing in the formula toolbar.

Moreover, this is possible by a formula, by using CHAR(10) as the enter character:

```
CONCATENATE("First line";CHAR(10);"Second line")
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I was hoping to add the line break to the text inside the format of a number. Currently the number is formatted with the format code MMMM "Direct Hours". I've tried \n, \r, ctrl-M... I guess this isn't possibe.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a formula like;

```
=TEXT(a4,"MMMM") & CHAR(10) & "Direct Hours"
```

where A4 is the cell with the date value for the month you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

CHAR(13) is a carriage return, so using CHAR(10) followed by CHAR(13) do the trick.